# How to deny a user in a role unless they are in another role in .NET c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, authorization

I'm working on a legacy system that that contains multiple users that can have 1 or more roles assigned to them.
For whatever reason, any Administrator has the Admin role assigned to them plus every single other role.

The problem comes with this configuration settings:

```
<location>
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" roles="ROLE1"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

Because admins have 'ROLE1' assigned to them, they will be denied access.

I know I can fix it by allowing every role except "ROLE1" but there are loads of them and it'd be a maintenance nightmare.

Is there any combination of allow and deny that would deny "ROLE" unless the user was also a member of the "Admin" role?

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't Admins only be given the Admin role? Which should override the other roles.  Or would this also be difficult to change at this stage?

Comment: Yes they should but that would require me analyzing all the code to see the impact. I may have to do that but was wondering if there's a quick config change I can make.

Comment: did you get a solution for this? I have another question similar to this one. Please answer there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21703895/issues-in-allow-and-deny-in-asp-config-authorization-and-location-elements

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it enough to allow Admin specifically before your deny rule?
The authorization rules are checked from top to bottom until a match is found.

```
<authorization>
    <allow roles="Admin"/>
    <deny users="?" roles="ROLE1"/>
</authorization>
```

Comment: Pretty sure I've tried that and it didn't work. I'll try again though and report back...